# why this \newcommand doesn't work in \align environment?

Tags: math-mode, macros, equations, errors, environments

I'm trying to use the 'newcommand' in the environment 'align', for that I created the 'newcommand' \rbel that is an 'arrow' with a 'n' below It. 
I put all the packages that I'm using.

```
     \documentclass[A4,12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,amssymb,amsthm,amsbsy}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{abraces}
        \usepackage{upgreek}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}   
        \usepackage{dsfont}
        \usepackage[hang,small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
        \usepackage{dsfont,float}
        \usepackage{color}
    \newcommand{\rbel}{
        \mbox{\;\rightarrow_{\hspace*{-0.3cm}{\small n}}\;~}
        }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align}
   \theta_n>1, \quad 
\dfrac{1}{\theta_n^2} \rbel 0
    \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

That gives these messages

```
"Missing } inserted. \end{align}"
"Missing \cr inserted. \end{align}"
"Missing $ inserted. \end{align}"
"Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}"
```

Comment: Your `\rbel`-command contains an `\mbox`. Even in math-mode the content of `\mbox`es isn't in math-mode any more as `\mbox`es switch to text-mode...

Comment: For avoiding linebreaks in math-mode usually nesting things in curly-brace-groups is sufficient. I.e., just do without the `\mbox`: `\newcommand{\rbel}{{\;\rightarrow_{\hspace*{-0.3cm}{\small n}}\;~}}`

Comment: This is not causing your issue but with your preamble the dsfont package is loaded twice.

Comment: There is also \mathmbox from mathtools.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want an arrow with “n” underneath:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rbel}{\xrightarrow[n]{}}

\begin{document}

\[
\theta_n>1, \quad \dfrac{1}{\theta_n^2} \rbel 0
\]

\end{document}
```

The error is because you're exiting from math mode when in `\mbox`.

I removed all the unnecessary package; please, take note that the option for A4 paper is called `a4paper`, not `A4`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It works if the `\mbox` is replaced by `ensuremath`. Furthermore the code causes some warnings. `A4` is no valid option for the `article` class and `\small` is ignored in math mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,amssymb,amsthm,amsbsy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[hang,small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{dsfont,float}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\rbel}{
\ensuremath{\;\rightarrow_{\hspace*{-0.3cm}{n}}\;~}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\theta_n>1, \quad 
\dfrac{1}{\theta_n^2} \rbel 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```